# The Hardy-Littlewood-Sobolev Inequality

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality

Let $f:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb C$, $n\ge 2$.
I saw the line that the inequality
$$
\left\| |x|^{-1} * |f|^2 \right\|_{L^\infty} \le
C\|f\|_{L^{\frac{2n}{n-1},2}}^2
$$
with some constant $C>0$.
Here $L^{p,q}$ denotes the Lorentz space and * denotes the convolution.
How can I prove the inequality above?
It seems like Hardy-Littlewood-Sobolev inequality, but I am wondering what happens if the left hand side takes $L^\infty$ norm.

Comment: See http://math.mit.edu/~lguth/PolyMethod/lect30.pdf for a proof of HLS in Chapter $3$.